# Why there are two authority files created by startx?

Tags: x11

In my laptop I have a minimal X server installation:

```
# dpkg -l *xorg* *xinit* | grep '^.i'
ii  xinit                        1.3.4-1        i386         X server initialisation tool
ii  xorg-sgml-doctools           1:1.11-1       all          Common tools for building X.Org SGML documentation
ii  xserver-xorg                 1:7.7+7        i386         X.Org X server
ii  xserver-xorg-core            2:1.16.4-1     i386         Xorg X server - core server
ii  xserver-xorg-input-evdev     1:2.9.0-2      i386         X.Org X server -- evdev input driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel     2:2.21.15-2+b2 i386         X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
#
```

There is no display manager installed nor a desktop environment. Only [minimalistic window manager](http://dwm.suckless.org/) and X server is sterted with `startx` command. Now `startx` calls `xauth` twice:

```
xauth -q -f "$xserverauthfile" << EOF
add :$dummy . $mcookie
EOF
```

..and

```
xauth -q << EOF
add $displayname . $mcookie
EOF
```

First one creates the authority file in `/tmp/`(for example `/tmp/serverauth.DrFpkBArQq`) and second one creates the authority file in `$HOME/.Xauthority`. Content of the files can be seen below:

```
# ls -l /tmp/serverauth.DrFpkBArQq 
-rw------- 1 root root 48 Dec 31 00:41 /tmp/serverauth.DrFpkBArQq
# xauth -vf /tmp/serverauth.DrFpkBArQq list
Using authority file /tmp/serverauth.DrFpkBArQq
T60/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  16b9dc1ae9969b5a807848b7ade44278
# 
# ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority 
-rw------- 1 root root 97 Dec 31 00:41 /root/.Xauthority
# xauth -v list
Using authority file /root/.Xauthority
T60/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  16b9dc1ae9969b5a807848b7ade44278
T60:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  16b9dc1ae9969b5a807848b7ade44278
#
```

Why there are two authority files?

Comment: I suspect the one in `/tmp` is intended for use by daemon applications that want to open windows on the user's display.

Answer (score 1):

This is to close a security hole in certain rare scenarios where the X server would or should not be able to access the user's `~/.Xauthority` or `$XAUTHORITY`. For example, the normal cookie file might be on a shared drive and might already contain a cookie for `localhost:0` for a different machine. The X server gets access to a temporary file that only contains its own cookie, and the same cookie is added to the normal file if `startx` has access to it and there isn't already a cookie for this display name. See [the commit that introduced this](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xinit/commit/startx.cpp?id=dd7fee44b126636d6c3edd9e325ce411e3ae5d78) and [bug #3078](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3078).